# Pack adjacent integers in Python

Tags: python

I wanna do this:

In an input file of comma separated list of positive integers, pack all two or more similar adjacent numbers e.g

```
in_values = 28, 30, 45, 28, 28, 40, 40, 40, 45, 678, 567, 555, 555, 555, 555, 
6, 8, 23, 34, 34, 90

expected output = 28, 30, 45, 28:2, 40:3, 45, 678, 567, 555:4, 6, 8, 23, 34:2, 90
```

I tried doing it using for & while loop but could not figure out how to skip multiple/duplicate entries in a for loop.

```
def packValues(ints):
    L = []
    for i in range (len(ints)-1):
        if not ints[i] == ints[i+1]:
            L.append(ints[i])
            continue
        c = 1
        while ints[i] == ints[i+1]:
            c += 1
            i += 1
        L.append(str(ints[i]) + ':' + str(c))
    print(L)
in_values = 28, 30, 45, 28, 28, 40, 40, 40, 45, 678, 567, 555, 555, 555, 555, 6, 8, 23

packValues(in_values)
```

Output (incorrect !) is:

```
[28, 30, 45, '28:2', 28, '40:3', '40:2', 40, 45, 678, 567, '555:4', '555:3', '555:2', 555, 6, 8]
```

Comment: @S3DEV it will not work if he have for example: values = 28, 28, 1, 2, 3, 28.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code snippet here will produce your expected output. I just added an else block to your if-statement and removed the while block.

```
def packValues(ints):
    L = []
    c = 1
    for i in range (len(ints)-1):
        if not ints[i] == ints[i+1]:
          if c > 1:
            L.append(str(ints[i]) + ':' + str(c))
            c = 1
          else:
            L.append(ints[i])
        else:
          c = c + 1
    L.append(ints[-1])
    print(L)
in_values = [28, 30, 45, 28, 28, 40, 40, 40, 45, 678, 567, 555, 555, 555, 555, 6, 8, 23]

packValues(in_values)
```

Output:

```
[28, 30, 45, '28:2', '40:3', 45, 678, 567, '555:4', 6, 8, 23]
```

**EDIT:**
This will also take into account last adjacent values now.

```
def packValues(ints):
    L = []
    c = 1
    for i in range (len(ints)-1):
      if ints[i] == ints[i+1]:
        c = c + 1
        continue
      if c > 1:
        L.append(str(ints[i]) + ':' + str(c))
        c = 1
      else:
        L.append(ints[i])
    if c > 1:
      L.append(str(ints[-1]) + ':' + str(c))
    else:
      L.append(ints[-1])
    return L

in_values = [28, 30, 45, 28, 28, 40, 40, 40, 45, 678, 567, 555, 555, 555, 555, 6, 8, 23]
print(packValues(in_values))
in_values = [28, 30, 555, 555, 555, 6, 8, 23, 40, 40]
print(packValues(in_values))
```

Output:

```
[28, 30, 45, '28:2', '40:3', 45, 678, 567, '555:4', 6, 8, 23]
[28, 30, '555:3', 6, 8, 23, '40:2']
```

Comment: try your code with for example in_values = [28, 30, 555, 555, 555, 6, 8, 23, 40, 40], it will not work

Comment: @ncica thanks for pointing that out! I adapted the code accordingly

Comment: you're welcome. it was just comment with good intent. We are all learning  :)

Comment: Thanks for the help !! I also got stuck with the last element problem & solved it using a workaround which works but your solution is much more elegant... This is what I did as workaround:      ints.append('dummy')

Answer (score 0):

You can use a check if the previous value is include as below:

```
def packValues(ints):
    L = []
    prevVal=None
    for i in range (len(ints)-1):
        if ints[i] == prevVal:
            continue;
        if not ints[i] == ints[i+1]:
            prevVal=ints[i];
            L.append(ints[i])
            continue
        c = 1
        while ints[i] == ints[i+1]:
            c += 1
            i += 1
        L.append(str(ints[i]) + ':' + str(c))
        prevVal=ints[i];
    print(L)
in_values = 28, 30, 45, 28, 28, 40, 40, 40, 45, 678, 567, 555, 555, 555, 555, 6, 8, 23

packValues(in_values)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
values = 28, 30, 45, 28, 28, 40, 40, 40, 45, 678, 567, 555, 555, 555, 555, 6, 8, 23, 34, 34, 90

i = 0
# pack = [[number, streak_count], ...]
pack = [[values[0], 1]]

for value in values[1:]:
    # if the current value is the same as the last value, increment the frequency
    if value == pack[i][0]:
        pack[i][1] += 1
    else:  # if the value is a new value, add it to `pack`
        pack.append([value, 1])
        i += 1

output = []
for n, f in pack:
    if f > 1:
        output.append(f'{n}:{f}')
    else:
        output.append(n)

print(output)
```

Output:

```
[28, 30, 45, '28:2', '40:3', 45, 678, 567, '555:4', 6, 8, 23, '34:2', 90]
```

Comment: The author only asks to pack *adjacent* integers, not an overall count.

Answer (score 0):

```
in_values = [28, 30, 45, 28, 28, 40, 40, 40, 45, 678, 567, 555, 555, 555, 555, 6, 8, 23,40,40]
streak_count = []
counter = 1
for i in range(len(in_values)):
    if i != (len(in_values) - 1):
        if in_values[i+1] == in_values[i]:
            counter += 1
        else:
            streak_count.append( "{}:{}".format(in_values[i],counter) if counter > 1 else in_values[i] )
            counter = 1
    else:
        streak_count.append("{}:{}".format(in_values[i], counter) if counter > 1 else in_values[i])

print (streak_count)
```

output:

```
[28, 30, 45, '28:2', '40:3', 45, 678, 567, '555:4', 6, 8, 23, '40:2']
```

Comment: Thank you very much ncica. Yes this solution also works !!